# objective-c dateFromString returns nil on specific date

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The date is always nil, but if I change the dateString to any other date like 03/01/1975 it works normally. Any idea?

```
NSString *dateString = @"05/01/1975";    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"us"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:gbLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: I tried you code it's giving 1975-04-30 18:30:00 +0000 in log console!

Comment: make sure dd and MM is correct on dynamic data also debug and print string

Comment: It's always showing nil :/

Comment: @AliZahr write NSLog(@"%@",date); below last line and check are you getting null?

Comment: I am not getting it nil !  Do you want to use current date ? @ALI

Comment: @kb920 yes it gives null. Is there anything that may affect it?

Comment: @JamshedAlam I am using a date picker, it works normally on almost all dates, but I found buggy on this date by chance.

Comment: @AliZahr Try my code Its working

Comment: @Jecky Nothing is working :/

Comment: Just Put whole Code It's Working I check It @AliZahr OR what do you want explain

Comment: I think that you may explains a few things: If you test the code you posted here, does it work? If YES, it means that the issue may be on your `UIPicker` stuff, could be a invisible character causing the issue, or something else, but then, we may need more information one that picker management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *dateString = @"05/01/1975";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy"];
NSDate *anotherDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",anotherDate);
```

**It will give output like this**

1975-05-01 00:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
- (NSDate *)getPickerDateForString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDate * dt;
    if (!dateFormatter)
    {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dt = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I do not need this date format, plus it's equivalent to my code.

Comment: when you used yyyy/MM/dd it's giving null!